# Why the dynamic solution to vertex cover does not prove anything?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, np-complete

The dynamic programming solution implemented [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertex-cover-problem-set-2-dynamic-programming-solution-tree/) runs in polynomial time, as discussed [here on slide 18](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec21.pdf). My question is, why does this algorithm not hold value? Why cannot it be reduced to all other NP-complete problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is only for binary trees, not general graphs. The problem for general graphs is NP-complete, but for binary trees it is not.

Suppose that $A$ is an instance of an NP problem. Since vertex cover is NP-complete, you know that you can map $A$ to an instance of vertex cover (i.e. an undirected graph $G$) in polynomial time. However, there is no guarantee that $G$ will be a binary tree, so the algorithm you have might not work on $G$. So, you will not be able to use this reduction to solve the instance $A$ of your original problem.

Comment: Aren't trees a type of graph as well?

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if it is more helpful now.

Comment: Definitely helps. Thanks